# ¿Como puedo recorrer Objetos de un Objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola comunidad, soy nuevo en Angular, estoy consumiendo una API HTTP desde AWS. Cuando el front-end hace GET me devuelve un JSON con tres objetos (Count, Items, Scanned) algunos objetos fueron agregados por api Gateway, pero yo solo necesito Items pero no sé cómo puedo recorrer solo los ítems y obtener sus propiedades (id,name,Price) y agregarlos a las tarjetas que asigne como la del ejemplo en el html…. Alguien me puede ayudar.

En la línea 19 del html, agrego{{ítems | json}} y me devuelve todos mis ítems pero en formato json, y los quiero tomar por separado para agregarlos a mi tarjeta.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes para mostrar el código, apenas es legible y además no podemos pegarlo a una respuesta. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

deberias formular mejor tu pregunta, pero hay te va tu con un ngfor avanzas cada objeto, tienes una lista de objetos en formato json que cada uno tiene 3 propiedades. Investiga como extraer y/o mapear objetos con una función de flecha mediante TypeScript así entenderás mejor la abstracción de ellos

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]